# ANSI C library for Aspect-Oriented Programming

Tags: c, aop

I'm searching for a good ANSI C library for Aspect-Oriented Programming.

Some desired features are:

- Accessing and modifying arguments of the target function.
- Making the target function return and controlling the return value.

I found aspeCt C (https://sites.google.com/a/gapp.msrg.utoronto.ca/aspectc/home), reading the documentation it seems to have everything I need, but when, following the instructions, I run make to compile and pass the tests, the tests fail.

There is any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can try  [AspectC++](http://www.aspectc.org/)
is a project that extends the [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) approach to C/C++.

For example if you want to a simple C program using Aspect:

```
int main() {
    printf("world");

}
```

And then you will have an aspect.cc

```
before(): execution(int main()) {
    printf("Hello ");
}

after(): execution(int main()) {
    printf(" from AspectC ! \n");
}
```

You compile both with `> acc hello.ac world.mc`

And the result is:

```
gcc hello.c world.c
>./a.out
 Hello world from AspectC !
```